# Dynamic URLs with Ionic web app

Tags: ionic-framework, routes

My question is a bit abstract but the target is to build a specific functionality in my web app.

I need my app to receive a URL under his domain and get part of the link as an argument for other purposes.

Per example (kind of UX flow):

1. We have this app that does nothing apparently ionic-app.com
2. We put ionic-app-com/q932n9324n8324n932 on the internet navigator
3. The page ionic-app.com/welcome is shown and the string q932n9324n8324n932 appears like a html content

Any direct help is appreciated, but also any advice about where do I have to look for info about this is welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the URL in your app using `window.location` (Try it out yourself in the chrome console). When using "ionic-app-com/q932n9324n8324n932" you could use something like:

```
var foo = window.location.href.split("/"); // Split the URL at every slash
var param = foo[foo.length-1]; // Get the last element of the URL, this should be q932n9324n8324n932
```

Hope this helps!